# ¿Cómo llenar un combobox con un arraylist en java fx?

Tags: java, javafx

Lo que sucede es que estoy tratando de llenar un `combobox` con un `ArrayList` que tengo en una clase.

Éste es la forma en que intento llenar el `combobox` con el `array`:

```
@FXML
private  ComboBox cProfesor=new ComboBox();

@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    p= new ProyectoFinal1();
}    

public void setP(ProyectoFinal1 p) {
    this.p = p;
}

public void agregarMateria(){
    for(int i=0;i<p.getFacul().getListaProf().size();i++){
        cProfesor.getItems().addAll(p.getFacul().getListaProf().get(i).getNombre());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los combos en javafx usan genéricos. Eso quiere decir que debes indicar el tipo que va almacenar el combo en el momento de la declaración:

```
private  ComboBox<String> cProfesor=new ComboBox<String>();
```

Por otra parte para agregar elementos se usa el método `add`. Así debería funcionar:

```
public void agregarMateria(){
    for(int i=0;i<p.getFacul().getListaProf().size();i++){
        cProfesor.getItems().add(p.getFacul().getListaProf().get(i).getNombre());
    }
}
```

Si quieres que el combo tenga pares `nombre - valor` debes crear una clase con dos variables una id y una de valor y esa pasársela al combo. Por ejemplo:

```
ComboBox<Regiones> cmbRegion=new ComboBox<Regiones>();
cmbRegion.getItems().add(new Regiones(1, "Europa"));
cmbRegion.getItems().add(new Regiones(2,"America"));
cmbRegion.getItems().add(new Regiones(3,"Asia"));
//**Clase regiones
public class Regiones {
    private int id;
    private String nombre;  
    public Regiones() {
    }
    public Regiones(int id, String nombre) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return  nombre ;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias el primer ejemplo me funcionó muy bien